# Javascript calculation not working for second text field

Tags: javascript, html

I found some code on JSBin (http://jsbin.com/lejoxesari/1/edit?html,js,output) which works like a treat, until I try and adapt it to do more! Now I seem to have an error where it won't calculate the second field.

My edited code can be seen below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2015 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/fivesocaku/1/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>1.2m</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>1.8</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="R12" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="b12" type="hidden" value="5" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="R18" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="B18" type="hidden" value="2" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script id="jsbin-javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('qty').value;  
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('b12').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('R12');    
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        result.value = myResult;
        var myBox4 = document.getElementById('b18').value;
        var result18 = document.getElementById('R18');  
        var myResult18 = myBox1 * myBox4;
        result.value = myResult;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't seem to be getting any errors reported, but was wondering if someone could take a look and let me know where my error is.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    var myBox4 = document.getElementById('b18').value;
```

You are getting an element id which doesn't exist

```
   var result18 = document.getElementById('R18');  
   var myResult18 = myBox1 * myBox4;
   result.value = myResult;
```

The last assignment should be `result18.value = myResult` you are assignig to the same textbox twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myBox4 = document.getElementById('b18').value;
```

`b18` must be `UPPERCASE`

```
var myBox4 = document.getElementById('B18').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to get the element by id b18 instead of B18.
Also, you are assigning the value again to result (overriding it), instead to result18.

If I could offer my 2 cents, use more meaningful names for variables, and have some pattern for it (same casing, with/withour numbers etc)